# C#-RedisCache Search Engine ( Need an idea )

Tags: c#, .net, redis

I have demo project.I use redis cache for caching big data db to redis cache and in the UI part I have a component when user type something I will fetch all data in cache and map to my getModel then I search it. You need to know I use hash set. Codes are below : `public async Task AddAccommodationsHash()
{
var cacheKey = GenerateCacheKey("Accommodation");

```
var accommodations = await _service.GetAllAccommodations();

foreach (var accommodation in accommodations)
{
    db.HashSet(cacheKey, new HashEntry[] { new HashEntry(accommodation.AccommodationCode, accommodation.AccommodationName) });
}
return true;
```

}`
public async Task<IEnumerable> FindAccommodations(string searchQuery)
{
var hashEntries = await AccommodationHashGetOrSet(key);

```
var result = hashEntries
    .Where(e => $"{e.Name}-".Contains(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                $"-{e.Value}".Contains(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .OrderBy(e =>
    {
        var firstIndex = $"{e.Name}-{e.Value}".IndexOf(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        return firstIndex < 0 ? 1 : firstIndex;
    })
    .ThenBy(e =>
        $"{e.Name}-{e.Value}");

return MapAccommodationsToAccommodationGetModel(result);
```

}

My question is : how can I find acco without fetch all data in redis ?

Comment: Can we take this back a level? you have a redis hash keyed by the `AccomodationCode` (value is the `AccomodationName`), and you want to find all entries where either the hash field (accomodation code) or value (accomodation name) contains a particular value, case-insensitive; ordered by "the value beind searched is earlier  in the code, or earlier in the name if not in the code, then by code, then by name" is that right? and you want to do that directly in redis, rather than fetching everything in-process? have I understood the question correcty? Out of curiosity, how large is this hash?

Comment: yes you understood correctly and hash key has 20.000 ; 10.000 accoCode and 10.000 accoName

Answer (score 0):

Redis hashes are not designed for flexible searching; they are designed for "get (etc) the value where the key is *these exact bytes*"; they cannot do:

- key *contains* a value (at least, not efficiently - see below)
- case insensitive search
- value *is* or *contains* a value

There *is* the `hscan` command, which allows a pattern-match for "contains" on the key, but: it isn't case-insensitive, and it is *not* particularly efficient - it is a simple scan over the entire hash.

It sounds to me that if you want to store this data in redis, you would do well to look at the RediSearch module, which supports secondary indexing and text-search capabilities. This is a more complicated API, but frankly: hashes don't do what you want them to do, and if you try to hack it in manually into redis, you'll basically be reinventing RediSearch.